# How do functors act on image objects?

Tags: category-theory, functors

Suppose $C,D$ are (additive) categories and $F:C\rightarrow D$ is a functor. I want to know when is $F(\alpha\cdot C)=F(\alpha)\cdot F(C)$ where $\alpha\cdot C$ denotes the image of $C$ under the morphism $\alpha$. Is it true in general or do we have to impose restrictions on the categories or the functor? I tried to prove it as it seems to be a valid assertion but couldn't get anywhere. In my particular case, $C=D$ and $\alpha\in\operatorname{End}(C)$ is an idempotent morphism.

I am using the following definitions of images and kernels in additive categories. Suppose $A,B$ are objects in an additive category $C$ and $f\in\operatorname{Hom}(A,B)$.

The $Ker(f)$ is an object with a morphism $i:Ker(f)\rightarrow A$ such that the following sequence is exact:
$$
0\rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(-,Ker(f))\xrightarrow{i\circ-}\operatorname{Hom}(-,A)\xrightarrow{f\circ-}\operatorname{Hom}(-,B)
$$
The $coker(f)$ is an object with a morphism $q:B\rightarrow coker(f)$ such that the following sequence is exact:
$$
0\rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(coker(f),-)\xrightarrow{-\circ q}\operatorname{Hom}(B,-)\xrightarrow{-\circ f}\operatorname{Hom}(A,-)
$$
$Im(f)$ is defined to be $Ker(q)$ and $coim(f)$ is defined to be $coker(i)$.

Does anyone know how to prove that $F(\alpha\cdot C)=F(\alpha)\cdot F(C)$ under the relevant restrictions?

Comment: Isn't this basically what functoriality means?

Comment: I want to know if the image of a morphism, $\alpha$ in the first category is still the image of the morphism $F(\alpha)$ in the second category.

Comment: you will need at least abelian or something else to make sense of your question, respectively a forgetful functor to sets, both of which you currently do not assume. 
In general the image is the kernel of the cokernel of the map, so in order to control this in the terms of category theory you will need at least assumption on exactness.

Comment: @Enkidu For more context, I have 2 categories: $\tau\text{Mod}$ is the category of zigzag modules of a certain type and $\text{Filt$_n$}$ is the category of filtrations of length $n$. The first is abelian but the second isn't. There is a functor $R:\tau\text{Mod}\rightarrow \text{Filt$_n$}$ which induces an isomorphism $\operatorname{End}(\mathbb{V})\cong \operatorname{End}(R(\mathbb{V}))$. $\mathbb{V}$ is an object in $\tau\text{Mod}$. I want to show that if $\alpha\in\operatorname{End}(\mathbb{V})$ is idempotent then $R(\alpha\cdot \mathbb{V})=R(\alpha)\cdot R(\mathbb{V})$

Comment: how does your category of filtrations look like? it can be a lot of things, and more importantly, does it admit a forgetful functors to sets, or how is the image defined there?